# php, how to remove a directory with all of its content (recursive) but leave alone those branches where a file exists?

Tags: php, recursion, directory

How to remove a directory with all files and directories (recursive) but when there is a special filename, that tree and its children would survive?

```
protected function _removeDir ($dir, &$found)
{
// is this directory exist?
if (!is_dir ($dir))
{
    return false;
}

// is there .ignore?
if (is_file ($dir.'/.ignore'))
{
    $found = true;
    return false;
}

// now iterate
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileinfo)
{
    $absPath = $dir.'/'.$fileinfo->getFilename();
    if (is_file($absPath))
    {
        unlink ($absPath);
    }
    if (is_dir($absPath))
    {
        $this->_removeDir ($absPath, $found);
    }
}
if (!$found)
{
    rmdir ($dir);
}
return true;
```

}

but it trips on a non exists directory

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck and need concrete help? No one will just write that code and post it so that you can copy&paste it.

Comment: ok, editedok, editedok, edited

Comment: What do you mean by 'it trips an a non existing directory'. What should it do then, and what does it do then?